# Want to print the records with lower run order value using SQL in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Below is the table :

```
Master_Key  Slave_Key   Scenario_Code   Run_Order
1506        1447           S20             3
1506        2447           S20             1
3506        3445           S11             2
3506        4445           S11             4
```

Output I am expecting :

```
Master_Key  Slave_Key   Scenario_Code   Run_Order
1506        2447           S20             1
3506        3445           S11             2
```

so based on the minimum run_order value, i want the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `distinct on ()` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (master_key) *
from the_table
order by master_key, run_order;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b8517a6e12c7cdc6963c1a00d5c1f811)

Comment: hey.. got the output now.. I missed the star after Master_key. thanks man :)